# Python: find duplicate values

Tags: python, frequency

I have a dataset like this:

```
user_id     location
2222           23
2222           23
2222           24
2222           23
3333           24
3333           24
3333           24
```

I want to find the frequency of values in "location" for each distinct "user_id". But I don't want to have the frequency through the whole column. Just want to show the appearance of each item in location.

The result should be a new column like this:

```
user_id     location    frequency
2222           23          1
2222           23          2
2222           24          1
2222           23          1
3333           24          1
3333           24          2
3333           24          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a tuple array like this

```
tupleArray = [(2222,23),(2222,23)...]
```

You can build another frecuency array and check if the value before is the same to increase the value

```
tupleArray = [(2222,23),(2222,23),(2222,24),(2222,23),(3333,24),(3333,24),(3333,24)]

frecuencyArray = []

tempValue = 1

for x in range(len(tupleArray)):
  if (x-1>=0 and tupleArray[x][1]==tupleArray[x-1][1]):
     tempValue += 1
  else:
     tempValue=1

  frecuencyArray.append(tempValue)


print(frecuencyArray)
```

Test the code:

https://repl.it/repls/WavyLostDatamining

Comment: Python doesn’t have `++` operator. This is C-style code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question fully, but will give it ago.

```
dataset = [
  (2222, 23),
  (2222, 23),
  (2222, 24),
  (2222, 23),
  (3333, 24),
  (3333, 24),
  (3333, 24),
]

feq = {}

ret = []
for usr_id, loc_id in dataset:
  key = '{}.{}'.format(usr_id, loc_id)
  feq.setdefault(key, 0)
  feq[key] += 1
  ret.append((usr_id, loc_id, feq[key]))
```

The content for ret is:

```
[(2222, 23, 1),
 (2222, 23, 2),
 (2222, 24, 1),
 (2222, 23, 3),
 (3333, 24, 1),
 (3333, 24, 2),
 (3333, 24, 3)]
```

Comment: What is your python runtime version ?  Did you copy & paste the exact same code ?

Answer (score 1):

please paste a actual python data object definition, not a printout

```
d = """2222           23
2222           23
2222           24
2222           23
3333           24
3333           24
3333           24"""

d = [*map(lambda x: [*map(int, x.split())], d.split('\n'))]

d

Out[89]: 
[[2222, 23],
 [2222, 23],
 [2222, 24],
 [2222, 23],
 [3333, 24],
 [3333, 24],
 [3333, 24]]
```

then

```
df, c = [], 0
for a, b in zip(d, [d[0]] + d):
    c = c*(a == b) + 1  # count with reset if lagged b value != a
    df.append(a + [c])
df
Out[90]: 
[[2222, 23, 1],
 [2222, 23, 2],
 [2222, 24, 1],
 [2222, 23, 1],
 [3333, 24, 1],
 [3333, 24, 2],
 [3333, 24, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class for cases just like this.

```
from collections import Counter
frequencies = Counter((user_id, location) for user_id, location in data)
```

This will provide what is essentially a map from each `user_id`/`location` pair to the number of times they appear together.

To transfer this data back into your matrix format, try the snippet below:

```
new_table = []
for (user_id, location), frequency in frequencies.items():
    new_table.append([user_id, location, frequency])
```

Here's a [demo](https://repl.it/repls/LumberingDarlingArguments) so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the result is not correct. I don't want the frequency of each value in the whole column.